# Django: Return list of dicts for values_list?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got this query:

```
cities = ShippingPrice.objects.filter(city1__name__icontains=request.REQUEST.get('city','')).values_list('city1__id','city1__name').order_by('city1__name').distinct()
```

Which returns a list of lists. It would be nice instead of doing `.values_list('city1__id','city1__name')` I could write:

```
.values_list({'id':'city1__id','name':'city1__name'})
```

And it would return me back a lists of dicts, like

```
[{'id':4135,'name':'Seattle'},{'id':4154,'name':'Vancouver'}]
```

Are there any existing methods to do that?

---

I'm looking through the Django source code, but I'd have no idea how to override this:

```
def values_list(self, *fields, **kwargs):
    flat = kwargs.pop('flat', False)
    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError('Unexpected keyword arguments to values_list: %s'
                % (kwargs.keys(),))
    if flat and len(fields) > 1:
        raise TypeError("'flat' is not valid when values_list is called with more than one field.")
    return self._clone(klass=ValuesListQuerySet, setup=True, flat=flat,
            _fields=fields)
```

Answer (score 27):

Why not just use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) in the first place?

Comment: I got used to using `values_list`, I forgot what `values` actually did...haha. But still, I'd prefer to rename the fields. `city1__name` doesn't make a very nice key.

Comment: Remapping is the easy part though, via a genex in `dict()`.

Comment: Eh? Then I have to create another dict mapping `{'city1__name':'name'}` and do some crazy logic to convert it....that seems more verbose than using `values_list` and passing it through `[dict(zip(keys,values)) for values in values_list]`

Comment: too simple, does not compute.